# Extract month and year for new variable

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with a variable that has the date of orders `(MMDDYY10.)`. I need to extract the month and year to look at orders by month--year because there are multiple years. I am vaguely aware of the `month` and `year` functions, but how can I use them together to create a new month bin?

Ideally I would create a bin for each month/year so my output can look something like:

```
                    Date
Item    2011OCT 2011NOV 2011DEC 2012JAN ...
a         50      40       30     20
b         15      20       25     30 
c         1        2        3      4
total
```

Here is a sample code I created:

```
data dsstabl;
    set dsstabl;
    order_month = month(AC_DATE_OF_IMAGE_ORDER);
    order_year = year(AC_DATE_OF_IMAGE_ORDER);
    order = compress(order_month||order_year);
run;

proc freq data
    table item * _order;
run;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing your analysis, use an appropriate format.  `MONYY.` sounds like the right one.  That will sort properly and will group values accordingly.
Something like:

```
proc means data=yourdata;
class datevar;
format datevar MONYY7.;
var whatever;
run;
```

So your table:

```
proc tabulate data=dsstabl;
class item datevar;
format datevar MONYY7.;
tables item,datevar*n;
run;
```

Comment: Joe, you are just lighting up my world today. Can't thank you enough. I was just about to edit my question to include a new code for feedback--update above. But your suggestion seems like the more efficient way.

Comment: The problem (or benefit, sometimes) of changing it to a character field is that you end up with a different sort order . Your approach in the top is not unreasonable, if you don't mind the sort order being alphabetical by month, not in date order (though you have the wrong variable names in the compress).  Also, `CATS` function will do compress + concatenate in one.

Comment: Would I have to do a sort if I wanted to stratify by 'Item'?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing your analysis in.  If you do it in `PROC FREQ`, you would have to sort and use a `BY` statement unless you are okay with just a normal crosstab (what you have above is fine for that).  If you do it in `PROC MEANS` or `PROC TABULATE` or another class-statement procedure, you can use `CLASS` to stratify without a sort.

Comment: Sure, or TABULATE if that's what you want - depends on what you're after results-wise.  `TABULATE` is more similar to `FREQ` in terms of displaying primarily counts and %s while `MEANS` does other summarized statistics (though both overlap a lot).

Comment: So, if I wanted to create output like above, where it shows orders for each item by month/year, it would be ideal to use `proc tabulate` ? And code would look like: 
`data
   class Item
   format datevar MONYY7.
   var datevar
`

Comment: Awesome. Came out perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with nice trick.

```
data my_data_with_months;
    set my_data;
    MONTH = INTNX('month', NORMAL_DATE, 0, 'B');
run;
```

Always use it.